# Pymongo not detected by 2nd version of python

Tags: python, centos, pymongo

My OS is Centos 6.2
I had installed python 2.6 and pymongo and both worked correctly.

Then I installed another version - python 2.7 in a separate directory (/tmp/python_new). In /usr/bin, I linked python_new to the new version. I did not reinstall pymongo. And the new version is not able to import pymongo.

How should I make python_new to import existing pymongo properly ?

Comment: "I did not reinstall pymongo. And the new version is not able to import pymongo."  You should.

Comment: But both python versions co-exist in the same OS.. how do I make sure the new pymongo is reachable by python_new ?

Comment: If you haven't already (Python 2.7.9+ comes with pip, so skip this), [get pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) for your python 2.7 install (make sure you're calling the correct python when you run the get_pip script), call `pip install pymongo` (make sure you're calling the correct pip when you run `pip install ...`)

Comment: Done ! This saved my day.. you can put your comments as the answer and I'll mark it as accepted.